# Python is in path but can't open it in terminal

Tags: python

I tried to install the latest python version, it concluded and the path is correct in the user variables, however I can't open it in the terminal.

When I try to open I get this message:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\python.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\bin\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\bin\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.path = [
    'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\python39.zip',
    'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\python3.9',
    'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\lib-dynload',
    '',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000027c8 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

I also have no idea why there is a python.exe in an Inkscape folder. The previous version of python was installed there, which I also have no idea why.

Comment: Have you rebooted your computer since modifying your PATH? It takes a reboot for the changes to be made in terminals.

Comment: I think the operating system starts at the beginning of the PATH and the first place it finds python, it will execute that. If the Inkscape path is before the Python path, then the python.exe will be executed. You can fix by placing Python before Inkscape. In your terminal you can type `echo %PATH%` to get the current version of the PATH variable.

Comment: I uninstalled inkscape and it worked, but I'll try your suggestion to avoid any further errors.